# Why are my iPad landscape screenshots rotated the wrong way?

Tags: ipad, ios, photos

All my iPad landscape screenshots end up rotated to portrait view. In other words, they are 90 degrees turned the wrong way. It's annoying. No I don't have the rotation lock on when taking them. I am on 4.2, but it has always done this even before 4.2 update. I am jailbroken, so it may be one of the jailbreak apps. Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use the any TVOut app? (ie. mirroring to VGA)

Comment: Don't know if you're still interested in this question; I answered it before I noticed it was on the old side. Let me know if the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior and is not an issue with jailbreaking. Even my new iPad 2 straight out the box does this on 4.3. I see this as a bug and hope Apple fixes this.

The fastest and simplest iPad app that I've found that I like for rotating, cropping and flipping is called Crop Suey HD.

UPDATE: It appears as though iOS 5 has finally fixed this annoying bug. And the even better news is that they are now throwing in photo editing tools right in the photo viewer app; including the option to rotate.

Comment: It used to work if you used the rotate lock button, but then stopped. Maybe when they took the rotate lock away temporarily. I really hope you're right about IOS 5

Answer (score 0):

That is just the way it is... why... I don't know, but they can be rotated using either the photo app, or photoshop express.... don't remember which one I used...

Comment: I wish Photo.app WOULD have a rotate button! So you're saying that you're not jailbroken and it also happens to you?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am saying...

Answer (score 0):

When I did all the screenshots for my [Keynote for iPad book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321751396), I had to solve this problem. The easiest way to do it is with an application that we all have in the Applications folder on our Macs but usually don't think of: Image Capture. Connect your iPad via USB, then fire up Image Capture. There's a toolbar at the bottom of the Image Capture window with buttons that let you rotate selected shots 90 degrees left or right.

Better yet, you can use Automator to create an Image Capture plugin that performs a variety of image transforms. The one I created first rotates the picture 90 degrees left (Preview action), then converts it from the native PNG to TIFF (Preview action), then saves it to a specified folder (Finder action). The plugin appears in the Import To pop-up  menu in the Image Capture toolbar.

Comment: I'm not seeing any rotate buttons - [secreenshot] http://cl.ly/58BR

Comment: The other thing is, I know how to rotate them on the Mac. I'd probably just use Preview. But lots of these screenshots I just want to keep on my iPad and don't want to have to transfer anyway. I know of the many App Store apps that rotate. Obviously my real goal here is to make it not happen at all. I was hoping this was a bug.

Comment: If you make the Image Capture window wider, the rotate buttons will appear in the toolbar.